# C function point conceal some variable

Tags: c

When I do scientific calculation, I usually meet a occasion that I want to use different method to solve my question. I think a function pointer will be a good tool for me. However, these methods usually have some their own parameters such as thresholds or else. Can I use a function pointer to point them all? i.e. Can I conceal some parameters in C function pointer? I know fortran has alternative variable and matlab also can support it.
For example:

```
    float method_a(float *mod, int N, double pa);
    float method_b(float *mod, int N, float pb1, char *pb2);
```

Comment: Probably you can pass a function pointer which takes structure pointer (containing all possible arguments) as an argument and decode the structure pointer in your function implementation.

Comment: Can you determine how to call the function later?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. C function pointers are an address plus a prototype which describes the arguments as they are (in the notional machine) pushed onto the stack. You can't switch from one prototype to another easily.

What you can do is build your own dynamic resolution at run time on top of C function pointers. Another trick is to always pass a void * to a function pointer which gives it context. The function that calls the function pointer never examines this void *, just passes it through. But you can then cast to your own structure, and potentially switch on a value somewhere to call one of a list of possible functions.